# How match two arrays witch contain array of objects in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I send data to server and match returned data with sent data. If use expect.arrayContaining(array) to compare options and nested variants it swears on ids and fields that add db. How compare objects with arrays which contain arrays of objects ?

[Example](https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveDaringExam)

Data to send:

```
{
  "name": "red dress",
  "options": Array [
    Object {
      "name": "size",
      "variants": Array [
        Object {
          "name": "M",
        },
        Object {
          "name": "L",
        },
        Object {
          "name": "S",
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Returned data:

```
{
  "id": "dc67efd8-dcc4-43df-a8eb-9d95ea641749",
  "name": "red dress",
  "options": Array [
    Object {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "size",
      "productId": "dc67efd8-dcc4-43df-a8eb-9d95ea641749",
      "variants": Array [
        Object {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "M",
          "optionId": 1,
        },
        Object {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "S",
          "optionId": 1,
        },
        Object {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "L",
          "optionId": 1,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Test:

```
expect(body.data).toMatchObject(productData)
```

[image]

Comment: The answer below was not what I was looking for. This however did the trick perfectly and gives two solutions: what you need in the Jest expect, and how to extend Jest if you need this functionality in multiple tests

https://medium.com/@andrei.pfeiffer/jest-matching-objects-in-array-50fe2f4d6b98

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a `forEach` loop to check the relevant data? I presume from your sent data that what matters is the provided options and variants are included in the response.

```js
it('has provided options', () => {
  sent.options.forEach(o => {
    expect(received.options).toContainEqual(
      expect.objectContaining({ name: o.name })
    )
  })
})
```

Similarly for the variants:

```js
it('has provided variants', () => {
  sent.options[0].variants.forEach(v => {
    expect(received.options[0].variants).toContainEqual(
      expect.objectContaining(v)
    )
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `map` to filter only the key you want to check

something like:

```
expect(yourResponseObject.options.variants.map(e=>({e.name}))).to.include(["blue","red", ... ]);
```

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/